# Lucene indexes getting deleted on application restart

Tags: java, tomcat, indexing, lucene

I am stuck in a situation. The thing is when tomcat restarts , all my indexes get deleted (note i have explicitly commented out the code which was written to do the before mentioned). So when I start the application and go the search page, the indexes from previous restart remain intact. But as soon as I hit the search, I get `java.io.FileNotFoundException: no segments* file found in org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory@/home/<path>: files:`  And the entire indexes in the indexed folder location gets deleted automatically. I made sure no other application is running in different jvm context and no other indexwriter instance is initialized . So what i observed is as soon as the indexreader is initialized it deletes all the previous indexes and throws the before mentioned exception.

post the above exception, if i add new document to the index and search it , it works fine for that but i lose all the previously indexed data which forces me to rerun the full reindex and avoid restarting the application (because whenever i restart it and someone hits search the previous indexes get deleted)

```
public static IndexWriter getIndexWriter() throws Exception{
        IndexWriterConfig idc = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LATEST, TpCustomAnalyzer.getAnalyzer()).setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
        idc.setRAMBufferSizeMB(1024);
        String repositoryPath = RepositoryConstants.DEFAULT_REPOSITORY_PATH;
        try {
            return new IndexWriter(FSDirectory.open(new File(repositoryPath),new NativeFSLockFactory(new File(repositoryPath))),idc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

protected IndexSearcher getIndexSearcher() {
        try {
            if(searcher == null){
                IndexReader idxReader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File(repositoryPath)));
                searcher = new IndexSearcher(idxReader);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            TPLogger.getLogger().error("Unable to open index searcher", e);
        }
        return searcher;
    }
```

My class that does indexing.

```
/**
 * @author 
 * 
 */
public class TPIndexerJob implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        TPLogger.getLogger().debug("===== Started new Indexer Job ===============");
        TPIndexEvent indexEvent = null;
        try {
            IndexWriter idxWriter = ParserUtils.getIndexWriter();
            while ((indexEvent = TPIndexEventQueue.getNext()) != null) {
                TPLogger.getLogger().debug("Processing Event ====> " + indexEvent);
                IndexManager.processIndexEvent(indexEvent,idxWriter);
                TPIndexEventQueue.removeFirst();
                // Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            idxWriter.commit();
            idxWriter.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            TPLogger.getLogger().error("Error running indexer job",e);
        }finally{

        }
        TPLogger.getLogger().debug("===== End Indexer Job ===============");
    }

}
```

I close tomcat by pressing ctrl+c is it because of abrupt ending the indexes somehow get corrupted?

My index structure post closing tomcat consists of  below files:

[image]

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but I had a similar problem which I traced to the config file changing - when that happened, all indexes got deleted

Comment: config file ? as in what did it contain related to indexing?

Comment: I can't remember the file name, but it was where we defined custom types and how they would be indexed. If anything changed, all indexes would be deleted on start up. We got around it by deploying a second instance and letting the indexes rebuild then switching to it.

Comment: @Bohemian I think i got a hint of the solution ..https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/FSDirectory.html

Comment: @Bohemian i think as the gc collect is not getting done when the tomcat is closed and when i restart the app, the OS deletes the files.. check the MMapDirectory  section in the above link...